# Missing buttons in Opendialog with Styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, vcl-styles.-utils

I'm getting OpenDialog failing to show the images on buttons if using VCL.Styles and VCL.themes.

I have downloaded VCL.Styles.Utils but cannot see how to fix the issue.

This picture shows the problem (circles where Opendialog offers Up one folder etc.)

[image: open dialog with missing standard images]

Delphi 11

Comment: What do you mean by "downloaded"? (Update: Ah, I see. It's a third-party library that enhances VCL styles.) Also, if you don't like bugs, quality issues, and accessibility issues, you should not be using VCL styles at all.

Comment: You could have linked to "_have downloaded VCL.Styles.Utils_" - the internet works through links.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using [Jerry Dodge's advice on using VCL Styles Utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808832/tfileopendialog-with-vcl-style-on-win-10-64-bit-open-button-appears-as-radio-bu)

it involves adding `Vcl.Styles.Utils` and `Vcl.Styles.utils.StdCtrls` to the implementation section of the unit, and setting `UseLatestCommonDialogs`  to false.

CHeers

Comment: Is it really worth it, to make your app less functional, less accessible, and less robust, only to get a non-standard UI?